Water stopper in a door-less shower frame
I have a door-less shower frame. As a result water spills out to the floor all around the outside of the shower.
Is there some water stopper I can use that do not damage the tiles on the floor.
I usually use a squeeze or mop the flower outside the area that the shower door should have been right after the shower
Photo of the shower bellow. You can see that there is no door


and


A shower curtain?

@crip659: How can I install a shower curtain? The only "frame" side walls are a glass wall and the actual wall. Those constutes the frame

There are many different ways that curtain rods can be attach.  Spring tension, suction cups, glue, screws into the wall, and probably other types.  The ones mounted into the wall are usually strongest/do not need TLC.  Adding a picture might give someone else ideas.

@Jim, We don't use your shower and can't see what you do, so a picture would help a lot to know what exactly you have.

If only there was a photo so we could see the geometry of your problem...

@RMDman: Added a photo

@Huesmann: Added a photo

Hi Jim, unfortunately, the photo you have posted doesnt give any more information.  Try taking a photo from outside the shower.  If you are using your phone, you can zoom out to X0.5

@RohitGupta: I added more photos

@Jim unfortunately, you don't give us a reverse angle so we can see what you have between the edge of the glass panel, and the wall opposite the shower fixture.  You may be able to put up a tension rod.

@Huesmann: What do you mean by reverse angle? From the side?

Caulk the glass?

@Jim "so we can see what you have between the edge of the glass panel, and the wall opposite the shower fixture."

@Huesmann: I dont understand that sentence. Which one is the wall opposite to the shower fixture? From where I took the photo? The one to the left of the glass?

@Jim when you sit at a table opposite someone else, where are you sitting?  Where are you facing?

@Huesmann: Can you please rephrase? I assume by shower fixture you mean the shower faucet. I am taking the photo and I am in the opposite side of the faucet directly in front of it. So you must mean something else.

OMG you are being obtuse.  Stand at the wall with the plumbing, with your back to the wall.  Take a photo of the wall you have not yet shown us.

Yes, you can buy a "Shower Threshold Water Dam" from Amazon (USA):
https://www.amazon.com/Shower-Threshold-Water-Barrier-67/dp/B0D76GS8T6
It may be that this product has different names, etc., in other countries. (I don't recommend or dis-recommend that particular linked product. It's just the first in the list returned.)
I had a problem like yours, and bought an extra-tall shower curtain first, but even with the shower curtain 2 millimeters or so above the tile, there was still "bounce-out" splashing outside the shower area. So I installed the water dam as a bottom seal, with the shower curtain hanging just inside it. This got rid of most of the problem (it doesn't do anything for when you pull the curtain back and lean out of the shower to yell at someone that is trying to tell you about a phone call...)
The product is a length of some rubbery material (silicon, silicone, silly-putty...) and maybe some plastic end-caps for appearance. You generally either receive some adhesive, or have to provide your own. I provided my own. For me, my shower had large-format tiles on the floor (> 1 foot / side) so there were few grout gaps. I chose to leave an adhesive gap at the grout lines, so that outside water might be able to go back into the shower area. If you have small tiles, I think you'll just have to go right over the grout with the adhesive.
NOTE: Make sure you have "finished" with your shower tiles and grout before you try to install the water dam. If you are going to seal the grout, put the sealer down before you try to install the water dam. It'll be a huge pain otherwise. Also, note that the adhesive may work so well that pulling up the dam pulls out a chunk of grout, so be ready for that (I have no idea if this could/would/will happen. But it's the worst possible thing that might happen, so plan for it!)


How can I install a tall shower curtain if the only frame available is a glass sidewall and the actual wall? This constitutes the frame of the shower 2) I am not the owner of the particular bathroom. From what you describe it could damage the tiles

